# Who can explain the execution that the <-done will run after close

Tags: go

I can't understand this program `for select`, so I need help to explain the order of this program,

```golang
    done := make(chan interface{})
    go func() {
        time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
        close(done)
    }()
    workcount := 0
loop:
    for {
        select {
        case <-done:
            break loop
        default:
        }
        workcount++
        fmt.Println(workcount)
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Achieved %v cycles of work before signalled to stop \n", workcount)
```

Comment: Which part confuses you? `for {}` is a loop. `select` is a select statement.

Comment: Note that "please explain this code" questions are generally considered by nature to be too broad to be permissible here. "Why does X happen before Y?" with a [mcve] can be on-topic, but the goal is to make the question as explicit and narrow as possible, describing exactly what you expect, why you expect it, and what you see instead. See [How to handle “Explain how this ${code dump} works” questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253894/how-to-handle-explain-how-this-code-dump-works-questions) on [meta].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    // Our communication channel is created
    done := make(chan interface{})

    // run this function as goroutine
    go func() {
        // wait/sleep 5 seconds
        time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)

        // close our communication channel
        close(done)
    }()

    // initialize workcount with 0
    workcount := 0

loop:
    // loop
    for {
        // read channel data
        select {
        // if channel is closed break this loop, break = stop!
        case <-done:
            break loop

        // default do nothing
        default:
        }

        // if our channel doesn't send anything, just add +1 to workcount
        workcount++

        // print workcount
        fmt.Println(workcount)

        // wait 1 second before we run this loop again
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    }

    // so workcount is 5, cuz our goroutine will send term signal after 5 seconds
    fmt.Printf("Achieved %v cycles of work before signalled to stop \n", workcount)
```

A much cleaner way to solve this issue would be

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    // sends after 5 seconds to this channel https://golang.org/pkg/time/#After
    timeout := time.After(5 * time.Second)

    // sends each second to this channel https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Tick
    tick := time.Tick(1 * time.Second)

    // our workcount var
    workcount := 0

    // for infinite
    for {
        // waits for data on each channel
        select {
        // fired if time.After wrote in timeout
        case <-timeout:
            fmt.Printf("Achieved %v cycles of work before signalled to stop \n", workcount)
            return
        // fired if time.Tick wrote in tick
        case <-tick:
            workcount++
            fmt.Println(workcount)
        }
    }
}
```

You run your code in main function so we need to return. We gonna fix this code using return

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    // Our communication channel is created
    done := make(chan interface{})

    // run this function as goroutine
    go func() {
        // wait/sleep 5 seconds
        time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)

        // close our communication channel
        close(done)
    }()

    // initialize workcount with 0
    workcount := 0

    // loop
    for {
        // read channel data
        select {
        // if channel is closed break this loop, break = stop!
        case <-done:
            fmt.Printf("Achieved %v cycles of work before signalled to stop \n", workcount)
            return

        // default do nothing
        default:
        }

        // if our channel doesn't send anything, just add +1 to workcount
        workcount++

        // print workcount
        fmt.Println(workcount)

        // wait 1 second before we run this loop again
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    }
}
```

Comment: very thanks，but i have some problem the channel will cloesd at 5 second,in 5 second the case doesnt run ? if i dont close this channel ,cant do <- done?will run default but the default is empty ,why workcount will add +1 ,dont know the order ,can show number about program run order

Comment: Reading from closed channels always returns immediately, with a default value. (0, false, "", etc.)  `default` is picked immediately if no other case can run.

Comment: default is empty so the program will run workcount++? then continue for loop ,when 5second , the case <-done will run ,so break the loop? then run fmt.Printf?  i run this program ,i found the program will show `1 2 3 4 5 ...` after 5 seconds. why program will print information after 5 seconds?

Comment: Thank you very much,  can you add the number of the program running, so that I can clearly understand the order in which it runs.

Comment: What do you mean by order? The program runs from top to bottom

Comment: i want know the `case <-done` will run after 5seconds right？why？ the channel not a buffered channel only have one  value ,if i didnt send any value to it ,it has a zerovalue, the zerovalue of interface is nil so <-done will read nil  right？why i need close？

Comment: @SebastianWaldbauer, ...as a note for the future, see [How to handle “Explain how this ${code dump} works” questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253894/how-to-handle-explain-how-this-code-dump-works-questions) on [meta], and the "Answer Well-Asked Questions" section of [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer); it can avoid a lot of trouble to get someone to narrow and clarify their question *before* trying to answer it, so you don't find out you answered the wrong question after already putting effort in.

Comment: @Bobby, ...it would have very helpful to have had the content you just put in your last comment included in the question itself, as that explains what it specifically is about the execution path that's surprising to you, vs making someone guess what you do and don't already know.

Comment: yes the order mean the program runs from top to bottom,sorry for my english.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks , i am new come to stackoverflow.....

Comment: @SebastianWaldbauer  hi bro why <-done will run after close ?